# Create a entity framework LINQ group join query to return a subset of properties from DTO and a list of another DTO, ASP.net core

Tags: asp.net, list, linq, join

So, I tried searching and couldn't really find an answer that was explicit enough and guided me to my solution so I thought I would add my problem and ultimately my solution for others to benefit.

Pardon my newness to SO (consider this my start of getting my reputation up), let me know if I do anything incorrect or forget anything.

I am trying to:

1. Create a controller that queries a database for all the users and their roles.
2. Return the list of unique users id's and email address with a List of roles.
3. The email address and roles are in separate tables and the pkey/fkey is the user id
4. The roles are returned as a list containing my AllUserInRolesDto

Every example I looked at on SO or other sites only provided examples of returning anonymous data objects back. I don't have a lot of LINQ query syntax so had me stuck for an hour or so.

**Here is my DTO**

```
namespace Lib.Dtos
{
    public class AllUserInRolesDto
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public List<RoleDto> Roles { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleDto
    {
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

**I have a business layer that defines the LINQ query**

```
public List<AllUserInRolesDto> UserAllRolesGet()
{
    List<AllUserInRolesDto> getAllUsersRoles = (from u in _context.Users
                            join r in _context.UserInRoles on u.UserId equals r.UserId
                            into ur
                            select new Lib.Dtos.AllUserInRolesDto()
                            {
                                FullName = u.Fullname,
                                Email = u.Email,
                                Roles = ur //this was the problem line and what the docs were describing
                            }).ToList();

    return getAllUsersRoles;
}
```

**...and my controller**

```
[HttpGet("GetAllUserRolesList")]
public IActionResult GetAllUserRolesList()
{
    List<Lib.Dtos.AllUserInRolesDto> allUsers = _userBL.UserAllRolesGet();
    return new JsonResult(allUsers);
}
```

**my solution**

After taking a step back for a second I realized I actually wasn't returning the right object back to my roles property...and so need to iterate over my roles and create a list from them. Here is what worked.

```
public List<AllUserInRolesDto> UserAllRolesGet()
{
    List<AllUserInRolesDto> getAllUsersRoles = (from u in _Context.Users
                            join r in _context.UserInRoles on u.UserId equals r.UserId
                            into ur
                            select new Lib.Dtos.AllUserInRolesDto()
                            {
                                FullName = u.Fullname,
                                Email = u.Email,
                                Roles = .Select(x => new Lib.Dtos.RoleDto() { RoleName = x.RoleName }).ToList() //Changed to this
                            }).ToList();

    return getAllUsersRoles;
}
```

Anyway, probably a pretty dumb mistake, but had me stuck for a bit. Maybe this helps someone in my same position or if someone has a comment of how I could have improved this or used a different approach I am open to hearing suggestions.

Comment: You don't need to use explicit Joins in Linq if you're using Entity Framework (or the older, now obsolete LinqToSql) and have set-up your entity relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I assume you're using Entity Framework, and that you have your DB model defined with relationships. This means you don't need to use explicit JOINs in your queries: you can use navigation properties instead.
- Your "business layer" (note that you don't necessarily always need a business layer) should only work with Entity types and should not use DTOs (as DTOs belong to your web-service, in the same way that View-Models belong to a web-application).

  - If your "business layer" just consists of predefined queries, I recommend defining them as static extension methods for your `DbContext` and returning `IQueryable<T>` instead of as materialized `List<T>` as this enables your consumers to perform further operations on them (such as additional filtering or sorting and paging).

I recommend doing it like this instead:

```
// Queries methods (i.e. "business layer" queries)
public static class QueriesExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<User> GetAllUsersAndTheirRoles( this MyDbContext db )
    {
        // I assume `UserInRoles` is a linking table for a many-to-many relationship:
        return db
            .UserInRoles
            .Include( uir => uir.User )
            .Include( uir => uir.Role )
            .Select( uir => uir.User );
    }
}

// Web-service controller:
[HttpGet("GetAllUserRolesList")]
[Produces(typeof(List<AllUserInRolesDto>)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllUserRolesList()
{
    List<User> usersList = await this.db
        .GetAllUsersAndTheirRoles()
        .ToListAsync();

    List<Lib.Dtos.AllUserInRolesDto> usersListDto = usersList
        .Select( u => ToDto( u ) )
        .ToList();

    return new JsonResult( usersListDto  );
}

// Entity-to-DTO mapping functions (if you have a lot of DTOs and entities, consider using AutoMapper to reduce the tedium)
private static AllUserInRolesDto ToDto( User user )
{
    return new AllUserInRolesDto()
    {
        FullName = user.FullName,
        Email    = user.Email,
        Roles    = user.Roles.Select( r => ToDto( r ) ).ToList()
    };
}

private static RoleDto ToDto( Role role )
{
    return new RoleDto()
    {
        RoleName = role.RoleName
    };
}
```

Comment: That is very helpful. I have to admit that I follow your approach much more easily than the existing code base I am working with. Thanks for providing additional guidance.